# App not showing in Google's manage third party apps section of user when users login using "Sign in with google"

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, google-signin

I am providing sign in with google functionality on my application. Users are able to successfully login using that but my application is not showing in "Manage third party apps" section of user's google account when they login. So they do not have an option to revoke access for my app. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here I want my app to be listed in users "Manage third party apps" section when they login successfully.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are miss understanding what third party apps is.  You may want to consult [Manage third-party apps & services with access to your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en)

> For example, you may download an app that helps you schedule workouts with friends. This app may request access to your Google Calendar and Contacts to suggest times and friends for you to meet up with.

Third party apps use Oauth2 to request your consent for the application to access your data.  When you consent to this the application in question is given a token (refresh token) which will allow them to access your data until you revoke that access. They can access this data without you being there.  So they could have something running every night to harvest your data.  They have access even when you are offline.  The way you revoke it is though the [security](https://myaccount.google.com/security) page on your google account.

Sign-in does not grant any access in that manner. For signin to work you the user must be behind the machine when it is running.  The application you signed into cant access your data when your offline.

There is no way for you to know which applications you have signed in using your google account.  Unless they also requested some Oauth2 consent.

So again sign in is Open IdConnect and does not make it by itself a third party app.  They have no access to your data after you are gone. Signin only works when the user is behind the machine.